# Создать массив переменных, хранящих указатель на график jqplot

Tags: javascript, jquery

Требуется создать большое количество графиков в одной разметке, чтобы позже их можно было отключать/подключать к визуализации входящих данных. Рабочий код вроде:

```
    var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [data1,data2,data3], plot_options1);
```

Не годится. Графиков много и желательно иметь доступ к их указателям в теле цикла, но конструкции вроде:

```
    var plotDataArr = [];
    plotDataArr[0] = $.jqplot('chart1', [data1,data2,data3], plot_options1);
    plotDataArr[1] = $.jqplot('chart2', [data1,data2,data3], plot_options2);
    ...
```

Или через объект, полям которого присваиваются результаты $.jqplot(...), или динамический перебор имён созданных переменных:

```
    for (let i = 0; i < plotCount; i++) {
       // некоторый код
       eval("plot"+i).replot();
    }
```

Терпят фиаско, сообщая, что: - "Не удалось получить свойство 'replot' ссылки, значение которой не определено или является NULL"

Можно конечно всё оставить как есть и для каждого прикрученного графика мотать портянку кода в поисках общего места определения процедур, выделенного в отдельный блок, но что-то мне подсказывает, что грамотность разработчиков изобразивших сие, не ограничилась такими узкими рамками. Правда, найти решение не удалось.

Помогите, люди добрые. :3

Comment: Проблема явно не в массиве.. так как не разницы, присваивать переменной или элементу массива. точно не нужно использовать eval.

Comment: В конце концов, можете найти строку, где вылетает ошибка и посмотреть, что есть null и почему...

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста рабочий пример, в котором присвоение указателя на график НЕ в переменную, а элементу массива, не вызовет у Вас ошибки при попытке доступа к свойствам этого указателя.
Строку искать не нужно, ошибка всегда там, где я вызываю методы объекта графика, через указатель, сохранённый не в глобальной переменной, а в элементе глобального массива, или объекта. Иными словами:

        plot1.replot();
Работает, а:
        plotDataArr[0].replot();
Не работает.

Comment: Функции не имеют информации о том, куда результат их выполнения будет направлен или чему присвоен, поэтому ошибка явно не в этом. Я бы на вашем месте открыл дебаггер да проследил значения переменных в критических точках. Ошибка приведённая выше означает, что некая переменная, от котороый вы пытаетесь получить replot равна undefined | null, стоит выяснить почему она null.. Если выложите код, где возникает ошибка, наверняка разберёмся

Comment: От всей души благодарю Вас за настойчивость, которой Вы побороли мою лень, сопротивлявшуюся желанию попробовать на примитивном примере.

К сожалению, у меня нет возможности использовать дебаггер и прочие тулзы для аудита HTML и происходящих в нём событий. Я использую HTML-разметку как шаблон,используемый в Win контроле Shell.Explorer, чтобы получить функционал этих замечательных поделок,рождённых сообществом JavaScript разработчиков,поэтому и "промазал".

У меня был вызов функции использующий имена переменных, после замены их на массив. Как раз то,о чём Вы и говорили.

Мой низкий поклон!

Comment: Анн нет, ещё один косячёк непонятный:
[Как прикрутить события 'resize' в цикле](https://jsfiddle.net/p02hbh51/)?
Внутренний алерт вызывается только по событию и его счётчик 'i' = количеству контейнеров + 1, будто цикл просто прокрутил его до финиша.

В этом месте теперь тоже эта ошибка выскакивает.

Comment: а какая версия js? es6 можно?

Comment: кажется вот так должно работать, там два варианта https://jsfiddle.net/8het5bhb/1/

Comment: Благодарю! Нашёл решение закинув конструкцию описания события в тело функции . [Так](https://jsfiddle.net/p02hbh51/1/). Хотя, у Вас, безусловно наглядней. На окружение сильно влияет установленная на машине версия IE, со всеми вытекающими. Но, ещё раз спасибо за наводку и Ваше время.